# WKInterfacePicker setValue and pickerAction infinite loop

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity, wcsession

Main app sends data to watch, and watch sets the picker index by using:

```
[picker setSelectedItemIndex:val];
```

This in turn, will fire up the picker action. However my picker action sends data to phone (using `sendMessage`) which in turn replies back to watch... and that goes on forever.

How can I cancel the picker action for `setSelectedItemIndex:`? WKInterfacePicker doesn't have a `removeTarget:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove the action. Instead, you have a few options to choose from to simply stop the cycle from happening by:

- Only setting the picker's value when the initial message is received, not when the response is received.

  *If the watch says, "The picker index is 3," and the phone replies, "Roger, the picker was set to 3," why would you want your watch code to set the picker based on the response to something the watch initially sent? This seems to be the crux of the issue, and would be the optimum solution.*

  Use a different key for the response, if necessary, to help any shared code distinguish between the types of messages.
- Not setting (or sending) the picker's value, when it already matches the picker's current selected index.

  *You'd have to maintain a property to keep track of the current value, as the picker's properties are write-only and can't be read.*
- Using a different `WCSession` method (such as `updateApplicationContext`) which is designed not to resend data when it matches the most recent `applicationContext`.